# What is the difference between [expanded] and (opened) in mat-expansion-panel?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Can't understand the difference b/w opened & expanded. If the panel is expanded then would it be right to say that opened is also fired at the same time?

Comment: if you see the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) you has `@Input`s -are properties of the object that you can use in .html like `[property]="variable"`-, `@Outputs` that allow you call to a function, you write `(output)="myFunction($event)"`, and `Methods` that allow you, using a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) execute "someaction" that change the **aparency** of the mat-expansion-panel -a template reference variable also allow us to access to the "properties" (the Inputs) of the element

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the difference is the following:

- *expanded* is a boolean, wether the panel **is** expanded or **not**.
- *opened* is an EventEmitter that is fired everytime the panel gets opened.